# Create an Automator action to insert a PDF table in Excel using data from picture

Tags: automator, ms-office, pdf, import

I'd like some help to create an Automator workflow to carry out the following please:

1. Select a PDF file containing a table of data
2. Convert the PDF file to an image
3. Open Microsoft Excel and import the contents of the image using the **Data** > **Data from Picture** option

Ideally, I'd love a single click operation where I simply select the PDF and the rest is completed ready for me to approve the import of the data.

Is this possible?

Comment: Converting text to an image, in order to read the image's text seems needlessly complex. Can the data not be imported directly from the PDF text? You might have more automation options that way.

Comment: Hello, the data that is being produced as a PDF from a patient management software doesn't covert properly into a spreadsheet even using Adobe Acrobat Pro. What does work is converting the PDF to an image then using get data from picture in excel. On the Mac, I've managed to easily create an automated action for converting the file to an image but this is where I'm stuck. I'd love to just drop the PDF into an automator workflow and the rest just happens so the output is a spreadsheet.

Comment: Excel has quite extensive AppleScript support, so you'd need to see if there's an AS command for Importing Data from Picture. If so, you'd then need to incorporate AppleScript into your workflow. (I bought the perpetual licence of Office 2021, which for some reason has Data from Picture excluded.)